# Programmatically set column nullable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, alter

I would like to remove `not null` constraint on a column, whatever its type is (`nvarchar`, `bingint`, `smallint`).

I am pretty sure it can be achieved using `sp_executesql` and building the `ALTER TABLE xxx ALTER COLUMN cccc type NULL` statement (by getting column type information from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`).

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create procedure sp_RemoveNotNullConstraint
(
    @tableName nvarchar(255),
    @columnName nvarchar(255)
)
as
begin

    declare @dataType nvarchar(255)
    declare @sql nvarchar(max);

    select @dataType =
        case 
            when C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is not null 
                then C.DATA_TYPE + '(' + CAST(C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as nvarchar(255)) + ')'
            else C.DATA_TYPE
        end
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
    where C.TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND C.COLUMN_NAME = @columnName

    set @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @tableName + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + @columnName + ' ' + @dataType + ' NULL;';
    exec sp_executesql @sql;

end
go
```

Answer (score 2):

No. The only way to remove the NOT NULL constraint is by using ALTER TABLE as you describe. Any variation on how you do it will come back to the same thing. However, if you do it through a GUI tool such as SSMS it *might* choose to drop and re-create the table (you shouldn't lose any data but it might take much longer than you imagined). In general be careful of using GUI tools to make changes to big tables.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this work :

```
    Declare @TableName As nvarchar(250)
           ,@ColumnName As nvarchar(250)
           ,@TypeName As nvarchar(250)

    Declare Cr Cursor for

    Select Top 10 obj.name As TableName ,clm.name As ColumnName ,typ.name As TypeName
    from sys.Columns As clm
    inner join sys.Objects As obj On obj.object_Id = clm.object_id
    inner join sys.types As typ On typ.system_type_id = clm.system_type_id
    where obj.type = N'U'
    And typ.system_type_id in (52 ,127 ,167)
    open Cr
    fetch next from Cr into @TableName ,@ColumnName , @TypeName

    while(@@fetch_status = 0)
    begin

      Declare @StrSQL nvarchar(max)

      Set @StrSQL = N' Alter Table ' + @TableName + N' Alter Column ' + @ColumnName + N' ' + @TypeName
      Print @StrSQL

    fetch next from Cr into @TableName ,@ColumnName , @TypeName

    End

    Close CR
    Deallocate CR
```